# Is there a way to get current path from HttpServletRequest in AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to get current path from `HttpServletRequest` in my `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Suppose my login page path is located at "/user/login" and make a post request to "/login". I want to be able to get the path "/user/login" after a user logged in succesfully. I did try using `HttpServletRequest::getRequesteURI`, but it returns "/login" instead of the current path.
Here's my example of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

```
class SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler: AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
   override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(request: HttpServletRequest,
                                        response: HttpServletResponse,
                                        authentication: Authentication) {
      val pathThatMakeThisRequest = request.requestURI // this returns "/login", I want to have "/user/login"
   }
}
```

Comment: The path is `/login` as that is what you are posting to.